# non-greedy multiline search in vim

Tags: regex, vim, multiline, non-greedy

I am trying to search ruby file and find all methods (before autoreplacing them later).
In vim, i use following regexp:

```
/\vdef.*(\n.*){-}end
```

However even though i use "{-}", it selects whole file's contents.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to match. How about if there is an `if ... end` condition inside a function?

Comment: yes i'll modify regexp later accordingly (like add positive lookahead for another def or smth like that). what i need right now is way to search it non-greedily

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[vim](/questions/tagged/vim) uses `\_.` to include the newline character to the common `.`.

```
/\vdef\_.{-}end
```

Answer (score 9):

In my version of Vim, you need to escape the `{`, as well as using `\_.` as other answers have said:

```
/def\_.\{-}end
```

Answer (score 5):

Try following regex.

```
/\vdef(\n|.){-}end
```

`.*` was culprit in your case

Comment: you can drop the `.*` after `def`. `\vdef(\n|.){-}end` would work just as well.